# How to read from a sqlite database and then display it and then delete it in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Hi I'm new to android and I got my location writing to a sqlite database but now I want the top line (ordered by id) to be read and sent to a server (got this working) and then deleted. is there some sort of code I need to do this as `if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {` dose not seem to work?

Comment: Dealing with databases isn't very complex for the beginners - refer to [this link](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/0).

Comment: Here you can find complete downloadable tutorial ... http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidSQLite.aspx So enjoy....with complete database help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
 cursor.moveToFirst();
while(!cursor.isAfterLast())            
{
 //do something 
 cursor.getString(columnname);  
 cursor.moveToNext();           
}
```